# Sencha Touch, How to change the tabpanel active item from a view

Tags: sencha-touch

Today I was trying to set the active item on a tabpanel from a button inside a view and thought of share the code, so its already a solved question. You can see my answer below.

Comment: You need to use a question answer format in StackOverflow. Alter your question, and post the answer as a solution, and select that as a answer to the question, thus closing the question.

Comment: Yes, but I'm glad he posted it, saved me some trouble today

Comment: just for anyone else looking at this, you can pass the index, the panel id or the panel object itself to set active item

Comment: Instead of Ext.getCmp() you should use Ext.Viewport.down() as this will stop as soon as it finds a match. getCmp will look through all items and that might take longer. And you should use itemId instead of id.

Answer (score 2):

(Changed to a community wiki answer to suit SO Q & A format)

The OP wrote:

> All you need is to assign an id for the tabpanel like the following code:

```
Ext.define("appName.view.Main", { extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel', id: 'mainTabPanel',
```

> Then use the following code to retrieve this tabpanel and set the active item

```
Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setActiveItem(1);
```

> Hope this will help someone

@Dawesi wrote:

> just for anyone else looking at this, you can pass the index, the panel id or the panel object itself to set active item

@Proto Bassi wrote:

> Instead of `Ext.getCmp()` you should use `Ext.Viewport.down()` as this will stop as soon as it finds a match. `getCmp` will look through all items and that might take longer. And you should use `itemId` instead of `id`.